# possible to construct java String from invalid code points?

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8

Is it possible to construct a String in java from invalid code points?

Is there any way a String str.getBytes("utf8") in java can return an invalid utf8 encoding?

The context is that I want to be able to serialize a String using an utf8 encoding as an array of bytes, and want to be able to deserialize it into as the same String.

I want to determine whether or not my (de)serialization code should first check if the array of bytes is a valid utf8 encoding or not.

Thank you.

Comment: Consider a string consisting only of a low surrogate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`CharsetEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html) and [`CharsetDecoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) classes in `java.nio.charset` to achieve precise control over how characters and bytes are translated back and forth.  In particular, [`CharsetDecoder.onMalformedInput()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html#onMalformedInput%28java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction%29) and [`CharsetDecoder.onUnmappableCharacter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html#onUnmappableCharacter%28java.nio.charset.CodingErrorAction%29) let you define how those conditions should be handled.  (The behaviour of the `String` constructor that takes a `byte[]` is undefined in these cases.)